# Why does use of Coq's setoid_replace "by" clause need an extra idtac?

Tags: coq

I encountered a strange situation using `setoid_replace` where a proof step of the form:

```
setoid_replace (a - c + d) with b by my_tactic
```

fails with `Error: No matching clauses for match goal`, but after appending an extra `idtac` to the tactic:

```
setoid_replace (a - c + d) with b by (my_tactic; idtac)
```

the proof succeeds. My understanding of `idtac` was that it was essentially a no-op.  Why does the presence of `idtac` make a difference here?

Here's the full code.  I'm using Coq 8.4pl6 through Proof General.

```
Require Import QArith.
Open Scope Q.

Lemma rearrange_eq_r a b c d :
  a == b  ->  b + d == a + c  ->  c == d.
Proof.
  intro a_eq_b; rewrite a_eq_b; symmetry; now apply Qplus_inj_l with (z := b).
Qed.

Ltac rearrange :=
  match goal with
  | [ H : _ == _ |- _ == _ ] => apply rearrange_eq_r with (1 := H); ring
  end.

Lemma test_rearrange a b c d e (H0 : e < b) (H1 : b + c == a + d) :  e < a - c + d.
Proof.
  (* Why is the extra 'idtac' required in the line below? *)
  setoid_replace (a - c + d) with b by (rearrange; idtac).
  assumption.
Qed.
```

Note: as Matt observes, `idtac` doesn't seem to be special here: it seems that any tactic (including `fail`!) can be used in place of `idtac` to make the proof succeed.

Comment: Strangely enough sequencing `rearrange` with anything seems to work.  For example, I get the same result when I do `setoid_replace (a - c + d) with b by (rearrange; fail).` or `setoid_replace (a - c + d) with b by (rearrange; exfalso).` or `setoid_replace (a - c + d) with b by (rearrange; auto).`  Very odd...

Comment: @Matt: Yes, I originally had `easy` in place of `idtac` (having got into the bad habit of adding `easy` whenever anything *almost* works).  I like `fail` though, for shock value. I might have to use that in the bug report. :-)

Comment: I've filed a bug report at https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jason Gross on the Coq bug tracker for explaining this.  This has to do with order of evaluation in the Ltac tactic language. In the failing case, the match in `rearrange` is being applied to the inequality in the immediate goal rather than to the equality generated by `setoid_replace`.  Here's Jason's response on the bug report:

> This is because the [match] is evaluated before the [setoid_replace]
>   is run.  It is one of the unfortunate trip-ups of Ltac that things
>   like [match] and [let ... in ...] are evaluated eagerly until a
>   statement with semicolons, or other non-match non-let-in statement is
>   reached.  If you add [idtac; ] before the [match] in [rearrange], your
>   problem will go away.